# WPF Binding to a value type

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

What binding path do I specify if I want WPF to bind to an `int`? Can I even do that?

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.DataContext = myValueType;
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("what do I put here?");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I clearly understand you, you can write something like this to bind int `myValueType` property to the textBox `Text`.

```
textBox.SetBinding( TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding( "DataContext" ) 
  { RelativeSource= new RelativeSource( RelativeSourceMode.Self ) } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.DataContext = this;
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("myValueType"));
```

Here the `DataContext` variable is the object that contains `myValueType` property. If the property is declared in the same class you can use `this`.

If you don't want to set the `DataContext` of your `TextBox`, you can use:

```
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("myValueType") { Source = TheObjectThatContainsMyValueProperty });
```

If you are not forced to use the code behind then prefer the xaml code. It is eaiser to write and understand these stuff in xaml.